Gulp Bundle/Build not Creating Files after Upgrade No Errors
I recently upgraded our webpart project from SPFX 1.12 to 1.19 Node to Version 18 and Gulp to version 5. I know - big changes. The build is fine no errors or issues but no files are created.
Because this upgrade included the tsLint depreciation I did remove the tsLint file but other than that no major changes except to PNPJS for the upgrade to PNPJS 4.0.
After doing a Build --ship and/or  Bundle --ship (which are both successful even with debugging) I run the gulp package --ship and get the error no manifest files can be found at manifest/release.
The files used to be stored at sharepoint/solution and I note that a gulp clean doesn't clear that folder anymore. If I manually create a manifest/release folder gulp clean will remove it, but gulp build --ship still won't populate it.
I do have a zippedPackage: solution/solution name defined in my package-solution.json I tried updating that to manifest/release/solution name and release/solution name but nothing works.
Also noted when I launch Gulp Serve although the Gulp Server is running it tells me it can't launch the webparts to ensure the server is running so pretty sure it's not creating the files to do this either. Any ideas?

Nothing suspicious if build or served or packaged via --verbose argument?

Well I rebuilt the whole project using a fresh SP19 regenerated Webpart to see if that did anything and now the release folder is getting created but when I run verbose I just get Webpack dist Error [Object][Object]. My lib folder is created correctly but my manifest file entries are blank. The names are listed but no values.

I've tried all the suggestions around the [object][object] error I have found with varying versions of react and pnp property controls to no avail.

I added the mgt-spfx dependency and now I have a package file. However SOME of the webparts in the package are throwing the Error [Object][Object] in Gulp Serve or after being deployed and used. The only error in the console is Cannot read Properies of undefined (reading 'id')

This GitHub thread you may find helpful--> https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9675

I faced somewhat similar issue. You can check it here Link
For me this [object object] issue occurred due to 2 reasons.

SPFX v1.19.0 supports React v17.0.1.
Unwanted localizedResources mentioned in config.json.


I am using React 17.0.1. I'll look into localizedResources mentioned in config.json you mentioned I haven't seen any errors nothing pops up during build or gulp serve except that Object Object...
